# FullText Search function error "The inline function cannot take correlated parameters or subqueries because it uses a full-text operator."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table setup with a full text catalog and index.

No matter how I try to call it, I always get this error:

> The inline function "dbo.fnPremCustomObjectSearch" cannot take correlated parameters or subqueries because it uses a full-text operator.

This is the table and configuration of the FTI:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tmpSearchCodeBehind (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CodeBehind VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_ID ON dbo.tmpSearchCodeBehind (ID)
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG tmpSearchCodeBehind_FTCat 
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON tmpSearchCodeBehind 
(  
    CodeBehind           --Full-text index column name   
    Language 1033        
)  
    KEY INDEX idx_ID  
    ON tmpSearchCodeBehind_FTCat
    WITH CHANGE_TRACKING OFF;
GO
```

I then created this function so that I can call on CONTAINS to do the search with a variable search term based on a value from a separate table:

```
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnPremCustomObjectSearch](
    @ObjectName AS VARCHAR(256)
)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(2048)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ReturnText varchar(2048) = ''
    , @SearchText VARCHAR(2048) = CONCAT('"', @ObjectName, '"')
    
    SELECT TOP 1 @ReturnText = @ObjectName 
    FROM dbo.tmpPremierSearchCodeBehind
    WHERE ID = 1 --Only the first row has the full value in CodeBehind that we need to search against
    AND CONTAINS(CodeBehind, @SearchTextLoc)
    AND CodeBehind LIKE CONCAT('%',@ObjectName, '%') --Weeds out any near matches...i.e. "EmployeeDetail$" would return if CommandText contained "EmployeeDetail" but not "EmployeeDetail$" 

    IF (@ReturnText = '')
        SET @ReturnText = NULL

    RETURN @ReturnText
END
GO
```

Though I have tried many attempts to call the function, this is what I originally had...

```
SELECT 
    Cob.ObjectType, Cob.ObjectName
    , dbo.[fnPremCustomObjectSearch](Cob.ObjectName) as CustomObjectFound
FROM tmpSearchCodeBehind Rpt
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT DISTINCT ObjectName, ObjectType 
    FROM tmpCustomObjectList 
    WHERE objectType != 'StoredProc'
    
) Cob
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY Cob.ObjectType, Cob.ObjectName
```

Even this causes it:

```
SELECT dbo.[fnPremCustomObjectSearch]('BugdgetedFTE') as CustomObjectFound
```

This works fine:

```
DECLARE @ObjectName AS VARCHAR(256) = 'BudgetedFTE2'
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(2048) = CONCAT('"', @ObjectName, '"')

SELECT * FROM tmpSearchCodeBehind Rpt WHERE CONTAINS(CodeBehind, @SearchText)
```

If I debug the function and set the incoming parameter to a known working value, it returns exactly what it should with no error.

I have used this exact same setup on a different set of tables and it works perfectly. Between my working example and this one, the tables and columns used for all this are setup exactly the same (in terms of column types, index configuration...everything!) I just don't get why one works and the other gives that error. I've Googled but get very limited results and haven't found anything that helps.

Comment: I guess you can either create the scalar function `WITH INLINE = OFF ` or switch to using an inline table valued function instead of a scalar one

Comment: Thank you kindly Martin. I added WITH INLINE = OFF and it ran without any further issues. Now to wonder and explore what implications that might have elsewhere, if any!